# How to replace paired square brackets with other syntax with sed?

Tags: bash, sed

I want to replace all pairs of square brackets in a file, e.g., `[some text]`, with `\macro{some text}`, e.g.:

```
This is some [text].
This [line] has [some more] text.
```

This becomes:

```
This is some \macro{text}.
This \macro{line} has \macro{some more} text.
```

- The pairs only occur on individual lines, never across multiple lines.
- Sometimes there might be more than one pair on a single line, but they are never nested.
- If a bracket is found alone on a line, without a pair, then it should not be changed.

How can I replace these pairs of brackets with this code?

Answer (score 17, accepted):

```
sed -e 's/\[\([^]]*\)\]/\\macro{\1}/g' file.txt
```

This looks for an opening bracket, any number of explicitly non-closing brackets, then a closing bracket.  The group is captured by the parens and inserted into the replacement expression.

Answer (score 42):

It took a little doing, but here:

```
sed -i.bkup  's/\[\([^]]*\)\]/\\macro{\1}/g' test.txt
```

Let's see if I can explain this regular expression:

1. The `\[` is matching a square bracket. Since `[` is a valid magic regular expression character, the backslash means to match the literal character.
2. The `\(...\)` is a capture group. It captures the part of the regular expression I want. I can have many capture groups, and in `sed` I can reference them as `\1`, `\2`, etc.
3. Inside the capture group `\(...\)`. I have `[^]]*`.

   1. The `[^...]` syntax means any character but.
   2. The `[^]]` means any character but a closing brace.
   3. The `*` means zero or more of the preceding. That means I am capturing zero or more characters that are not closing square braces.
4. The `\]` means the closing square bracket

Let's look at the line *this is [some] more [text]*

- In #1 above, I capture the first open square bracket in front of the word *some*. However, it's not in a capture group. This is the first character I'm going to substitute.
- I now start a capture group. I am capturing according to 3.2 and 3.3 above, starting with the letter `s` in *some* as many characters as possible that are not closing square brackets. This means I am matching `[some`, but only capturing `some`.
- In #4, I have ended my capture group. I've matched for substitution purposes `[some` and now I'm matching on the last closing square bracket. That means I'm matching `[some]`. Note that regular expressions are normally greedy. I'll explain below why this is important.
- Now, I can match the replacement string. This is much easier. It's `\\macro(\1)`. The `\1` is replaced by my capture group. The `\\` is just a backslash. Thus, I'll replace `[some]` with `\macro{some}`.

It would be much easier if I could be guaranteed a single set of square brackets in each line. Then I could have done this:

```
sed -i.bkup 's/\[\(.*\)\]/\\macro(\1)/g'
```

The capture group is now saying anything between to square brackets. However, the problem is that regular expressions are greedy, that means I would have matched from the `s` in `some` all the way to the final `t` in text. The 'x' below show the capture group. The `[` and `]` show the square brackets I'm matching on:

```
 this is [some] more [text]
         [xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx]
```

This became more complex because I had to match on characters that had special meaning to regular expressions, so we see a lot of backslashing. Plus, I had to account for regular expression greediness, which got the nice looking, non-matching string `[^]]*` to match anything not a closing bracket. Add in the square brackets before and after `\[[^]]*\]`, and don't forget the `\(...\)` capture group: `\[\([^]]*\)\]`And you get one big mess of a regular expression.

Comment: Fine explanation! However the replacement should be surrounded by `\macro{...}`

Comment: Minor fix... Edited my answer. On a small screen, it's sometimes hard to see the difference between `(` and `{`.

Answer (score 4):

use groups

```
sed 's|\[\([^]]*\)\]|\\macro{\1}|g' file
```

Answer (score 2):

The following expression matches the pattern `[a-z, A-Z and space]` and replaces it with `\macro{<whatever was between the []>}`

```
sed -e 's/\[\([a-zA-Z ]*\)\]/\\macro{\1}/g'
```

In the expression the `\( ... \)` form a match group that can be referenced later in the substitution as `\1`

Comment: This may be correct for the test data provided but `[^]]*` is a better fit.