# Escaping advanced regexp in bash

Tags: regex, bash, sed

```
#!/bin/bash
files=`find ./ -type f`
from='{trans("[ sometext ]")}'
to='{trans("sometext")}'

for i in $files
do
        echo "file: $i";
        sed -e 's/"$from"/"$to"/g' $i > "$i"_new;
        mv "$i"_new $i;
done
```

This is my script.
I would like to remove square brackets from trans function in many files.
I don't know how to escape that special characters in that strings.

Anyone could help me debug that?

For example:

```
{trans("[ sometext ]")} -->  {trans("sometext")}
{trans("[ sometext2 ]")} -->  {trans("sometext2")}
{trans("[ sometext3 ]")} -->  {trans("sometext3")}
```

EDIT:
Not duplicate in my opinion because of hard char combination.

Comment: Any reason that you need `from` and `to` to be inside variables?

Comment: No I don't really need this. It was only for clean code/better visibility.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to replace paired square brackets with other syntax with sed?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10646418/how-to-replace-paired-square-brackets-with-other-syntax-with-sed)

Comment: No it's not duplicate - I tried this in script ... it doesn't work...

Comment: Huh? These aren't bash regexes at all (bash regexes use `[[ $string =~ $regex ]]` invocation syntax). `sed` is not part of bash, and it works the same way no matter which shell you run it from.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would suggest removing the loop, which is going to give you trouble for awkward filenames, and instead using `-exec {} +` to call sed the minimum number of times necessary:

```
find . -type f -exec \
    sed -E -i.bak 's/(\{trans\(")\[ *([^ ]*) *]("\)\})/\1\2\3/g' {} +
```

This assumes that your version of sed supports `-E` for extended regular expressions and `-i` for in-place editing (creating a backup with suffix `.bak`).

The pattern captures three groups:

- `\{trans\("` the part leading up to the opening square bracket
- `[^ ]*` non-space characters inside the square brackets (this matches your examples `sometext`, `sometext2` and `sometext3`)
- `"\)\}` the part after the closing square bracket

The parts in between (square brackets and leading/trailing spaces) are dropped. As you can see, various regular expression metacharacters need to be escaped, such as `{`, `(` and `[`.

Comment: Thanks for makeing my mind clear. 
I did it wrong! Now it works!

Answer (score 0):

With bash, no need of sed.

```
find . -type f -exec bash -c 'for i do f="${i/[ /}";echo mv "$f" "${f/ ]/}";done' sh '{}' +
```