# Bash sed: replace tag within square brackets

Tags: bash, sed

In a bash script (newbie to bash), I have a variable like this: `"this is a message [REL]"` and I want to convert it to this: `"this is a message"`.

I tryed native bash string manipulation, like `CLEAN_MESSAGE=${MESSAGE#REL}` and didn't work so I'm trying with sed, I followed a few posts like this one: [How to replace paired square brackets with other syntax with sed?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10646418/how-to-replace-paired-square-brackets-with-other-syntax-with-sed#10646526) but no luck

This is my current status:

```
MESSAGE=$(cat $1) #A message with a tag [REL]
RELTAG=\[[REL]\] #A variable with regexp for tag, tryed \[REL\], \[(REL)\], \[\(REL\)\] and other variants
CLEAN_MESSAGE=$(echo "$MESSAGE" | sed "s/$RELTAG//") 
echo $CLEAN_MESSAGE
```

With some variants of the RELTAG I get *EL]* or *[RE*, but never the complete tag removed.

Help?

Comment: Try `sed 's/\[[^]]*\]//'`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `%` to remove at end of string

```
$ s='this is a message [REL]'
$ echo "${s% \[REL]}"
this is a message

$ # if variable contains the removal glob
$ r=' \[REL]'
$ echo "${s%$r}"
this is a message
```

See [wooledge Parameter Expansion](https://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashGuide/Parameters#Parameter_Expansion) for further reading

Comment: Thanks, why the need to scape the opening bracket but not the closing one?

Comment: @K.Weber I suppose that is because `[` indicates starts of character class.. and if that is not present, no need to worry that `]` is special..