# using sed to replace brackets with env var

Tags: bash, sed

I'm trying to replace a bracketed text like `[PROJECT_ID]` with and env var `PROJECT_ID`...I tried this:

```
export PROJECT_ID=adfaf@asdf.com
echo "[PROJECT_ID]" >> test.text
sed -i -e 's|[PROJECT_ID]|$PROJECT_ID|g' test.text
```

I get this:
`[$PROJECT_ID$PROJECT_ID$PROJECT_ID$PROJECT_ID$PROJECT_ID$PROJECT_ID$PROJECT_ID$PROJECT_ID$PROJECT_ID$PROJECT_ID]`

I've tried lots of different ways but just can't seem to get this to work

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19151954/how-to-use-variables-in-a-command-in-sed is *almost* a duplicate (gist: use double quotes). Additionally, you have to escape `[` and `]` with `\[` and `\]`, or every single letter will be replaced instead of the complete string. Summary: `sed -i "s/\[PROJECT_ID\]/$PROJECT_ID/g" test.text`.

Comment: This question addresses the square bracket issue: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10646418/how-to-replace-paired-square-brackets-with-other-syntax-with-sed

Answer (score 0):

- Each run you append the same line to text.txt. So sed processes many lines
- Single quotes like in `'s|[PROJECT_ID]|$PROJECT_ID|g'` use the text literally. But it seems, that you want to expand $PROJECT_ID.
- In this case `export` is not needed.
- It is not really clear, what you really want

Fixed code (my guess):

```
PROJECT_ID=adfaf@asdf.com
echo "[PROJECT_ID]" > test.text
sed -i -e "s|[PROJECT_ID]|$PROJECT_ID|g" test.text
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to escape the brackets with a backslash to match them literally.

```
PROJECT_ID=adfaf@asdf.com
echo "[PROJECT_ID]" > test.text
sed -i -e "s|\[PROJECT_ID\]|$PROJECT_ID|g" test.text
```