# Sed replace all digits within square brackets with a new line

Tags: regex, bash, sed

My question is a both a refinement and a continuation of [What's the regular expression that matches a square bracket?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/928072/whats-the-regular-expression-that-matches-a-square-bracket).

I am trying to create a regex for use within sed (GNU sed) 4.4 that will replace all digits surrounded by square brackets with a new line.

The sample text is generated by dumping a bash array to a file ("sentences.tmp"), yielding:

```
declare -a aRecs=([0]="" [1]="some text" [10]="some more text" [100]="three-digit text")
```

The diesired output is:

```
declare -a aRecs=(
"" 
"some text" 
"some more text" 
"three-digit text")
```

Originally, I tried the following regex:

```
\[\d*\]\=
```

...but both M. Nejat Aydin and dan said not to use /d in sed.  Thank you for that instruction.

The following regex (per M. Nejat Aydin) does give  the desired hightlight text match in xed 2.0.2:

```
\[[0-9]+]
```

[image]

However, when I run:

```
sed -i 's/\[[0-9]+]/\n/g' "sentences.tmp"
```

--or --

```
sed -i 's/\[[0-9]+\]\=/\n/g' "sentences.tmp"
```

There is no change within "sentences.tmp" upon file re-loead.

I experimented with various other forms (including replacing with 'xxx' in lieu of '\n' or '\n' or '\\n' with the same result.

My apologies for failing to provide a sample output.  I have amended the question to include the guidnace thus far.  Thank you.

Comment: `sed -E 's/\[[0-9]+]/\n/g'`. Don't use`\d` in `sed` regex.

Comment: `\d` isn't valid in sed. Use `[0-9]` instead. Ie. `sed -E 's/\[[0-9]+\]/\\n/g'` to replace with `\n` (literally). To replace with a linefeed, use a literal linefeed instead of `\n` (keeping the first back slash).

Comment: What is the expected output?

Comment: I have amended the question to address failings and suggestions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using `sed`

```
$ sed -i.bak 's/\[[^]]*]=/\n/g' input_file
declare -a aRecs=(
""
"some text"
"some more text"
"three-digit text")
```

Comment: Thank you  HatLess!

Using your regex I was able to find an approximate explanation at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10646418/how-to-replace-paired-square-brackets-with-other-syntax-with-sed

There are a lot of pointers to things I should read there.

Thank you.